# Why does the skin tingle after consuming beta alanine?

Tags: supplements

Many people notice a skin-tingling effect after consuming [beta alanine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-Alanine), but I found no explanation on *why* the skin is tingling and why the effect starts at the head first.

Perhaps someone can shed some light on this?

Comment: This is a nutrition question which are off topic according to the new [FAQ].